# Microsoft Accelerator library with Visual Studio F#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, microsoft-accelerator

I've downloaded and installed Microsoft Accelerator as stated in the manual, but when I try to create a project that uses `open Microsoft.ParallelArrays`, ParallelArrays is still not defined.

I tried going through the References to add Accelerator to the list but could not seem to find it.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I have found a file in another location that does work, but when I compile and run my test program it throws the error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Accelerato
r.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007
007E)
   at Microsoft.ParallelArrays.FloatParallelArray.AcceleratorNative.Create_FPA_F
A1D(Single[] values, IntPtr Length)
   at Microsoft.ParallelArrays.FloatParallelArray..ctor(Single[] values)
   at Program.Test1() in c:\users\misao\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ac
celeratortest\acceleratortest\Program.fs:line 10
   at <StartupCode$acceleratortest>.$Program.main@() in c:\users\misao\documents
\visual studio 2012\Projects\acceleratortest\acceleratortest\Program.fs:line 97
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Did you do this - Add a reference to System.Drawing and the managed Microsoft.Accelerator.dll (under the appropriate directory for your target e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Accelerator v2\bin\Managed\Release\Microsoft.Accelerator.dll

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit new to VS, how do I add a C:\ path as a reference?

Comment: Reference -> add reference -> Browse -> Browse

Comment: Says the C:\...\Accelerator.dll file could not be added. Please make sure the file is accessible, and it is a valid assembly or COM component?

Comment: For the latest error message - have you copied the native dll to the output directory

Comment: So, I'll need to copy the downloaded .dll to the directory listed in Reference -> Browse?

Comment: No - into the output directory where your resultant exe is built

Comment: Would we need to do this manually each time we use an external library, or is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

Add the dll 'Accelerator.dll' to your project. 
Right click on the project, Add / Existing Item. 
Then set this files 'Copy To Output' property to Copy Always.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to copy the DLL in your executable directory is still the best way to make it work without a problem for you, and especially avoid awful post : "System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Accelerato
r.dll'"